# How to take index, name and number as parameters?

Tags: arrays, function, processing

Hi i was given a task in Processing and the question is this "You are asked to store a small telephone contact list that can hold ten names and ten matching telephone numbers.  show how you would write a function that takes a name, a telephone number and index as parameters and sets the array(s) at the index position to the values given. Include in your answer code that checks the index given is a valid position in your array(s)."

I've come up with the code below

```
String[] names = new String[10];
int[] numbers = new int[10];
String[] contact = new String[10];

void setup() {
  names[0] = "p1"; 
  names[1] = "p2"; 
  names[2] = "p3"; 
  names[3] = "p4"; 
  names[4] = "p5";
  names[5] = "p6"; 
  names[6] = "p7"; 
  names[7] = "p8"; 
  names[8] = "p9"; 
  names[9] = "p10";

  numbers[0] = 1; 
  numbers[1] = 2; 
  numbers[2] = 3; 
  numbers[3] = 4; 
  numbers[4] = 5;
  numbers[5] = 6; 
  numbers[6] = 7; 
  numbers[7] = 8; 
  numbers[8] = 9; 
  numbers[9] = 10;

  for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    contact[i] = "Name:"+names[i] +" "+ "Number:" + numbers[i]+" ";
    println(contact[i]);
  }
```

}

But my teacher's comment to my code were this "So what I expected here was a simple function that took an index, a number and a name as parameters and then filled in the arrays at the index value with the values." I'm quite confused about this question, is void setup not a function? and i really don't know what it means by making index, number and name as parameters. So if anyone can point out to me thanks!

EDIT: improved code

```
void setup() {
  for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
    contactList(i, "aName", 123456789);//default value to all 10 elememnts
  }
}

void contactList(int index, String name, int number) {
  println (index, "Name:" + name, "Number:" + number); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how to write a function? Hint: you do, you wrote the setup() function! Can you write another function that takes parameters? Start with a simple function that just takes a parameter and prints it out. Work from there.

Here's a little example that takes a String as a parameter and prints it out, which is called from the setup() function:

```
void setup(){
   printMe("hello!");
}

void printMe(String text){
   println(text);
}
```

Recommended reading:

[Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor - Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

[Writing Your Own Functions - Static Void Games Tutorials](http://staticvoidgames.com/tutorials/basicConcepts/writingYourOwnFunctions)

Comment: Thank you, also your recommended reading is really useful too!!! i've added my improved code to the question